# Select the second element of the second section with same name, CSS - NTH

Tags: css, inheritance

In this example http://jsfiddle.net/rodrigolinkweb/k8qg14xL/ I need to select only "Container 12", how can I do this?

ps: note that both divs have the same class name "wrapper".

```
.container:nth-child(n+3){
   background-color: gray;
    color:white;
}
```

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">Container 1</div>
    <div class="container">Container 2</div>
    <div class="container">Container 3</div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">Container 11</div>
    <div class="container">Container 12</div>
    <div class="container">Container 13</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select them with the `.wrapper` class, like this

```css
.wrapper:nth-of-type(2) .container:nth-child(2){
   background-color: gray;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">Container 1</div>
    <div class="container">Container 2</div>
    <div class="container">Container 3</div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">Container 11</div>
    <div class="container">Container 12</div>
    <div class="container">Container 13</div>
</div>
```

If you want to select it from backwards you can use :nth-last-of-type() . Refer to the following fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qpcef1zy/)

No matter what content the `.wrapper` has `:nth-child` will select child based on its position where as `:nth-of-type` selects with appropriate attribute.

```css
.wrapper:nth-of-type(2) .container:nth-child(2){
   background-color: gray;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">Container 1</div>
    <div class="container">Container 2</div>
    <div class="container">Container 3</div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="wrapper">
<a href="#">Some link</a>
    <div class="container">Container 12</div>
    <div class="container">Container 13</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what if I have "<a href=###>" instead of "<div class="container">Container 11</div>"?

Comment: It still works the same way.  http://jsfiddle.net/qpcef1zy/1/

Comment: I have updated my answer, kindly check

Comment: updated mine, check it please

Comment: Here's the updated fiddle again http://jsfiddle.net/qzgxdut4/